# How to publish PostGIS Rasters in Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

How to publish PostGIS Rasters in Geoserver?

> gdalinfo landsat.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: landsat.tif
Size is 1773, 1428
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (177595.474744186009048,471385.819080783985555)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
 INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  177595.475,  471385.819) 
Lower Left  (  177595.475,  428545.819) 
Upper Right (  230785.475,  471385.819) 
Lower Right (  230785.475,  428545.819) 
Center      (  204190.475,  449965.819) 
Band 1 Block=1773x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=1773x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=1773x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

> step 1) raster2pgsql

```
  raster2pgsql -s 4737 -I -M -C landsat.tif -t 100x100 -l 2,4,6 public.land mosaic | psql -U dragonman -d nyc
```

step 2) MosicPlugIn install

> step 3) creat MOSAIC table

create table {schema}.MOSAIC (NAME varchar(254) not null,
     TileTable varchar(254)not null,
     minX FLOAT8,minY FLOAT8, maxX FLOAT8, maxY FLOAT8,resX FLOAT8, resY FLOAT8, primary key (NAME,TileTable))
   insert into MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', 'landmosaic');
   insert into MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', 'o_2_landmosaic');
   insert into MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', 'o_4_landmosaic');
   insert into MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', 'o_6_landmosaic');

> step 4) geoserver create config file (mapping, connenct, config xml file)

```
  create a directory /data/coverages this needs to contain 3 files: connect.pgraster.xml.inc, mapping.pgraster.xml.inc, oek.pgraster.xml
```

> step 5) geoserver store create publish

< >**Geoserver Error Log**

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to acquire test coverage for format:ImageMosaicJDBC
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:970)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:856)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:346)

Comment: Have you enabled Raster extension in PostGIS ?

Comment: Have you take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html)?